# Hooking asp.net core 2.1 into MSAL.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to hook MSAL.NET into my asp.net core web app, so that I can make use of Microsoft Graph API. I just want to allow my users to authenticate to MS (work/school account) so that I can access their calendar.

As far as I know, to do this, I need to:

1. Pass my user to Microsoft to authenticate (standard oauth dance)
2. Get the access code from a successful auth, and then hook that into MSAL.NET, effectively delegating token management to MSAL.NET

But I'm stuck with the auth-ing with MS part. In ASP.NET Core 2.1, the recommended way to get MS external login sorted is nice and simple - `AddMicrosoftAccount` - like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ApplicationId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Password"];
});
```

The problem here is that doesn't give you any hooks for when the authorization code is returned from MS. There are hooks for a successful ticket (i.e. when the tokens have been granted), but that's no good for MSAL.NET, because it requires you to use the codes with `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` to manage tokens.

The only way I can see that would allow me to hook into this is to use `AddOpenIdConnect` instead, because that offers an event for `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` that I could use to get the auth code and hook into MSAL.NET.

Is that possible to use, or is there a better way to get all this working?

Thanks